# Importing TensorFlow works in Jupyter notebook but not in IDLE

Tags: windows-7, python

I installed tensorflow2.0.0-alpha0 for Python 3.7.2 on Windows 7 SP1. It's importing fine in Jupyter notebook, but when I try to import it in IDLE or the Python interpreter invoked from the command line, I get this error message.

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SHARMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 47, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.msvcp_dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\SHARMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\SHARMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\Users\SHARMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\Users\SHARMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\SHARMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\SHARMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 55, in preload_check
    % build_info.msvcp_dll_name)
ImportError: Could not find 'msvcp140.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install this DLL by downloading Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 from this URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587
```

How can I fix this so that TensorFlow works in IDLE?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it seems there is a module missing. Maybe if you double check the dependencies, to see if everything is there...

Comment: The error says `ImportError: Could not find 'msvcp140.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed ...` Is [Microsoft Visual C++](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587) installed?

Comment: But the intriguing thing is it is importing and working fine in jupyter notebook. In addition to that msvcp140.dll is there in three different places within the python37 folder

Answer (score 0):

I copied msvcp140.dll from one of the subfolders in python37 and pasted it in the main python37 folder (which contains python, pythonw etc files). Now I am able to import Tensorflow in IDLE and python interpreter invoked from the command prompt.The problem I mentioned appears to be solved. But whether it is the correct solution or not I do not know. But so far there have been no problems.